# Jquery queued animation sequence with delay; need to repeat

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate, queue, repeat

I need the following code below, which animates a sequence of images, to run and then repeat indefinitely. Currently its on the page load and then just finishes. The url to see the animation is: http://marisspillanewines.com/dev/

Thanks! Mona

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#cork_CU").animate({left: '-20px',top:'-20px'}, { duration: 600, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#fisherman_CU").delay(4800).animate({left: '-20px',top:'-20px'}, { duration: 600, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#maris_CU").delay(8800).animate({left: '-20px',top:'-20px'}, { duration: 600, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#capsule_CU").delay(12800).animate({left: '-20px',top:'-20px'}, { duration: 600, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#numbers_CU").delay(16800).animate({left: '-20px',top:'-20px'}, { duration: 600, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#fisherman_CU").delay(4800).animate({left: '-700px',top:'600px'}, { duration: 0, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#maris_CU").delay(4800).animate({left: '-700px',top:'-600px'}, { duration: 0, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#cork_CU").delay(4800).animate({left: '700px',top:'600px'}, { duration: 0, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#capsule_CU").delay(4800).animate({left: '700px',top:'-600px'}, { duration: 0, queue: true, ease:true });
  $("#numbers_CU").delay(4800).animate({left: '700px',top:'-600px'}, { duration: 0, queue: true, ease:true });
});
```

Comment: here is the link: http://marisspillanewines.com/dev/

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Clean up your question so it's only a description of the problem vs. what you expect it to do, and the source. We're happy to help, just give us an idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: With your current approach it seems impossible. Try abstracting the different parts needed for your animation, you may want to create a jQuery plugin for ease of use. Don't hardcode the values, calculate the offset dynamically, etc...

Comment: Im trying to loop this sequence. So that when this all finishes, it replays. Please look at the link I commented above to see how the animation plays. Sorry I want to be clear I just dont know what else to say.

Comment: the problem is that I need different starting locations for each slide, I wasnt sure how to make that abstract. I dont think I would be cable of creating a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

for such timing issues in jQuery there is a [plugin jQuery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/). It shortens your code to the following. I suggest to give the images a common CSS class, e.g. "pic":

```
var startLeft = $('.pic').each().css('left'),
    startTop = $('.pic').each().css('top'),
    targetPos = {left:-20,top:-20};

var $frame = $('.pic').parent();

function setBack(index) {
    this.css({left:startLeft[index], top:startTop[index]}).appendTo($frame);
}

$(".pic").repeat().each($).then(setBack).animate(targetPos,600).wait(4000);
```

This solution is very generic as it doesn't depend on the actual number of images in your frame.

By using .appendTo($frame) we assure that the animated image is always topmost.

[.repeat()](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/repeat/.repeat.html) is a timing method from that extension, as well as the sequential loop via [.each($)](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/each/.each_sequential.html), and the deferring function [.wait(timeout)](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/wait/.wait_timeout.html).

To collect the start positions I used the short syntax with the parallel [.each()](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/each/.each_parallel.html).

Comment: thank you so much. And thanks for the great explanation. I have implemented it but I must have something wrong. Can you please look at my code to see if Ive done it right? http://marisspillanewines.com/dev/

Comment: hi Mona. I forgot the surrounding block $(function(){ … }); which makes the code run on dom-ready event. Currently its starting the loop when no ".pic" element exists.

Comment: another thing: ssrc="images/maris_CU.jpg" - there is one "s" too much at ssrc.

Comment: and you load a script  http://marisspillanewines.com/dev/scripts/jquery.path.js which doesn't exist anymore

Comment: the animation loop works very well - see http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/WNHTK/

Comment: absolutely perfect. Many many thanks Peter for the effort. I love this script.

Comment: hi Mona, by picking an answer as best solution for your question you help other people finding a good answer quickly. thx, Peter